# streaming video not working in IE

Tags: asp.net, streaming, video.js

Here my ideas:
1. Leech video from Free Hosting to my Server (OK)
Example: http://yanoshop.com/dms/xem/dms.aspx?url=http://up.4share.vn/f/3103020403020003/3830e2bfe4bdc4091f28a94d1fb9bf3d.webm.file
2. Then Streaming File from Server to Client (OK on FireFox and Chrome but IE)
Example: http://www.yanoshop.com/dms/xem/webm.aspx?u=http://yanoshop.com/dms/xem/dms.aspx?url=http://up.4share.vn/f/3103020403020003/3830e2bfe4bdc4091f28a94d1fb9bf3d.webm.file

Note:I'm making this running on Mobile using HTML5 (I'm using VideoJS Plugin)

Here the code i use:

```
//Create a stream for the file

        Stream stream = null;

        //This controls how many bytes to read at a time and send to the client
        int bytesToRead = 50000;

        // Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];

        // The number of bytes read
        try
        {
            //Create a WebRequest to get the file
            HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(downloadLink);
            fileReq.Timeout = 99999;
            //Create a response for this request
            HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

            if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
                fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;

            //Get the Stream returned from the response
            stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();

            // prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
            Response.Expires = 0;
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");

            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);

            //Indicate the type of data being sent
            Response.ContentType = ExtentionToContentType(filename);
            Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

            //Name the file 
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + filename);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());
            //Response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

            //Response.AddHeader("Accept-Header", stream.Length.ToString());
            int length;
            int count = 0;
            if (count == 0)
            {

            }
            do
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read data into the buffer.
                    length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                    // and write it out to the response's output stream
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data
                    Response.Flush();

                    //Clear the buffer
                    buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
                }
                else
                {
                    // cancel the download if client has disconnected
                    length = -1;
                }
            } while (length > 0); //Repeat until no data is read
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                //Close the input stream
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: here mp4 file: http://www.yanoshop.com/dms/xem/mp4.aspx?u=http://yanoshop.com/dms/xem/dms.aspx?url=http://up.4share.vn/f/2110191514131512/[JDS][PV]%20Touch%20%28Younha%29%20%28VietSub%29%20[640x480%20x264%20AC3][EA95CC8F].mp4.file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a WebM file, which Chrome and Firefox do support but IE9 doesn't.